# Rich Asserters in Botium Box community edition

Tags: botium-box

In Botium Box community edition, there is no option to perform Rich assertions.So how can we handle assertions in Community Edition botium box

Answer (score 0):

Rich assertions can be done with the [integrated Botium asserters](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/2293815/Botium+Asserters). They are available in all Botium flavours.